Unexpected behavior in ParametricPlot
I'm using the following commands to draw a ParametricPlot.
intmap = {-(((-2 + timep + tt - 
         2  timep  tt + (-1 + timep)  (-2 + tt)  Cos[tplot])  Sin[
        tplot])/(-1 + Cos[tplot])), 
  2 - 2   timep + tt + (-1 + timep)   (-2 + tt)   Cos[tplot]}

Show[
 ParametricPlot[{intmap /. { timep -> 1/10, tt -> 0}, 
   intmap /. { timep -> 1/10, tt -> 1}}, {tplot, 0, 2  \[Pi]}],
 ParametricPlot[
  intmap /. timep -> 1/10, {tplot, 0, 2  \[Pi]}, {tt, 0, 1}]
 ]

As you can see though, the interior shading is going outside the boundaries that are the edge of the plot. I'm sure this has to do with the singularity located at tplot=0, and I've already tried switching the order of the plotting variables in PP. When using Show to combine this with a plot of explicitly just the edges it seems like it's also missing some region. Are there any clever ways to get around this, or is it doomed to always have some sort of artifacts as a result of numerical methods approaching singularities?

Increasing the number of PlotPoints does not seem to fix this issue.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/308893/72111 PlotStyle -> Opacity[1]

@march increasing the number of plot points does appear to help,  it gets closer and closer as I increase the number of plot points, but it doesn't completely solve it.

@cvgmt that isn't help, it doesn't change the shaded region at all, just makes it darker. They used ParametricPlot to solve an issue, my issue is the behavior of ParametricPlot

Please note that  discontinuous mapping not always mapping the domain boundary to the image boundary.

In this case the transformation I'm making the boundary is getting plotted perfectly fine by ParametricPlot, it is only the interior shading that is coming out incorrectly.

Your error is using a finite timep, which means the inflection points are not hit exactly.  Try timep ->2000.

For what I'm using that variable for timep is to strictly be between 0 and 1.

If we zoom in the "problematic" region we can see what is going on. The region is simply overlapping itself like if you fold piece of paper to itself. The paper still has its boundaries but anyway now the inner part of the paper is outside its boundaries.
intmap = {-(((-2 + timep + tt - 
          2 timep tt + (-1 + timep) (-2 + tt) Cos[tplot]) Sin[
         tplot])/(-1 + Cos[tplot])), 
   2 - 2 timep + tt + (-1 + timep) (-2 + tt) Cos[tplot]};
ParametricPlot[
 intmap /. timep -> 1/10, {tplot, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {tt, 0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]



A more simple example. The "problematic" region is darker because of this overlapping.
ParametricPlot[{(t + r)^2, (t - r)^2}, {t, 0, 1}, {r, 1/10, 2}]



Illustration how the overlap is created. The curve goes through the overlap region twice.
pp = ParametricPlot[{(t + r)^2, (t - r)^2}, {t, 0, 1}, {r, 1/10, 2}];
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot[{(t + r)^2, (t - r)^2}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 9.5}, {-0.5, 4.5}}, Axes -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, 
   Epilog -> 
    Evaluate@{PointSize -> Large, 
      Point[{(t + r)^2, (t - r)^2} /. {{t -> 0}, {t -> 1}}]}], 
  pp], {r, 1/10, 2, 1/10}]



